# Currency symbol for users current locale

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my app I need to display the appropriate currency symbol for the user's current locale. I'm not displaying currency values, just the symbol.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NSLocale can do this:

```
NSString *sym = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the AppKit or the UIKit you can get that information from NSLocale.